# Using Python to execute cmd commands

Tags: python, cmd, io

Hello i have been playing around with python recently and have been trying to learn how to control external peripherals and i/o ports on my laptop.

I have been trying to disable USB ports and disable my network adapter. However when i run my program it does not work. The code does not have a specific syntax error but when it is ran nothing happens.

```
import subprocess


def main():

    print("PROGRAM STARTED")
    subprocess.call(["runas", "/user:Administrator", "cmd.exe /c netsh interface set interface '*' admin=disable"])

    print("Program Exited")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What happens when you run the command from *cmd*?

Comment: Can't reproduce. It asks for password (and when I provide one, since the user doesn't exist, fails).

Comment: Ive had the issue with all users i use, every user i have has access to administrator privileges so feel free to change the user. also to answer your first question it runs perfectly no errors but no execution of the command.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try to run such commands as admin in windows. This might help: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/05cce5f6-3c3a-4bb8-8b72-8c1ce4b5eff1/how-to-run-a-program-as-adminitrator-via-the-command-line?forum=w7itproappcompat

You can also modify your command to print the output in stdout to debug easily.
`print subprocess.check_output(['runas','/user:Bradley',  "cmd.exe /c netsh interface set interface '*' admin=disable")`

Comment: I ran that and got this error(b'Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.371]\r\n(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.\r\n\r\nC:\\Users\\Bradley\\Desktop>') i assume this has something to do with bytes due to the 'b' at the start?

Comment: @bradleyplater That is not an error you are printing a message.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue with the code. to start with i was using the `subprocess.call` function however trying to run the program with Administrator through python do it through command prompt and use this line of code instead

```
subprocess.run(["powershell","Disable-NetAdapter -Name '*'"])
```

Note* Yes i changed from cmd to powershell this is because the command was easier to use.